# I keep getting a HTTP 400 Bad Request error using urllib.request?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

So i have been sitting on this problem for a bit now, i keep getting a bad request error when running code below.

```
url = input("Twitter link: ")
print("\n")
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

name = soup.find('h1').a.text
location = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'ProfileHeaderCard- 
locationText'}).text
locationstrip = location.strip()
created = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'ProfileHeaderCard- 
joinDateText'}).text
birthday = soup.find('span', {'class' : 'ProfileHeaderCard- 
birthdateText'}).text
birthdaystrip = birthday.strip()
posted = soup.find('a', {'class' : 'PhotoRail-headingWithCount'}).text
postedstrip = posted.strip()

print("Info")
print("-------- \n")
print(name)
print(locationstrip)
print(created)
print(birthdaystrip)
 print(postedstrip)
url = "http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/" + name
formedurl = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/70.0.3538.102'})
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(formedurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
```

I Read that you need to specify a user agent so i did to make it look like a legit http request but i still get this error. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `name`?

Comment: Can't reproduce. The closest I get is 404 (obviously for values of `name` that generate urls for non existing pages)

Comment: Does `name` have characters that are illegal in a url?

Comment: @JohnGordon no it just uses the name that gets pulled from their twitter. I find it weird that it does not work since i tried webbrowser.open("http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/" + name) and that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to replace `space` with undescore `_` in `name`

```
name = name.replace(' ', '_')
url = "http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/" + name
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the headers from your browser and remove them one by one until you find the minimal set that works.